# Knockout js click event inside the model

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Below is my code containing post and comment functions. I am binding for view inside ul tag click events like `data-bind="click: addComment"` and  `data-bind="click: addPost"`. It's working fine.

My problem is when putting the `data-bind="click: addComment"` inside another view it won't work. I need to keep my `data-bind="click: addComment"` inside another view and must hit the `self.addComment` inside the Post Model - can somebody please help?

```
<div class="publishContainer">
<textarea class="msgTextArea" id="txtMessage" data-bind="value: newMessage,  jqAutoresize: {}" style="height:3em;" placeholder="What's on your mind?">   </textarea>
<input type="button" data-url="/Wall/SavePost" value="Share" id="btnShare" data-bind="click: addPost">
</div>
<ul id="msgHolder" data-bind="foreach: posts">
 <li class="postHolder">
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: PostedByAvatar }"><p><a data-bind="text: PostedByName"></a>: <span data-bind="    html: Message"></span></p>
    <div class="postFooter">
        <span class="timeago" data-bind="text: PostedDate"></span>&nbsp;<a class="linkComment" href="#" data-bind="    click: toggleComment">Comment</a>
        <div class="commentSection">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: PostComments">
                <li class="commentHolder">
                    <img  data-bind="attr: { src: CommentedByAvatar }"><p><a data-bind="text: CommentedByName"></a>: <span data-bind="    html: Message"></span></p>
                    <div class="commentFooter"> <span class="timeago" data-bind="text: CommentedDate"></span>&nbsp;</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="display: block" class="publishComment">
                <textarea class="commentTextArea" data-bind="value: newCommentMessage, jqAutoresize: {}" placeholder="write a comment..."></textarea>
                <input type="button"  value="Comment" class="btnComment" data-bind="click: addComment"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

//second view//
<div class="publishContainer">
    <input type="button"  value="Comment" class="btnComment" data-bind="click: addComment"/>
 <div>
```

And the JS:

```
//Post Model
function Post(data) {
  var self = this;
  data = data || {};
  self.PostId = data.PostId;
  self.Message = ko.observable(data.Message || "");
  self.PostedBy = data.PostedBy || "";
  self.PostedByName = data.PostedByName || "";
  self.PostedByAvatar = data.PostedByAvatar || "";
  self.PostedDate = getTimeAgo(data.PostedDate);
  self.error = ko.observable();
  self.PostComments = ko.observableArray();

  self.newCommentMessage = ko.observable();
  self.addComment = function () {
    var comment = new Comment();
    comment.PostId = self.PostId;
    comment.Message(self.newCommentMessage());
    return $.ajax({
        url: commentApiUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: ko.toJSON(comment)
    })
   .done(function (result) {
       self.PostComments.push(new Comment(result));
       self.newCommentMessage('');
   })
   .fail(function () {
       error('unable to add post');
   }); 
  }
  if (data.PostComments) {
    var mappedPosts = $.map(data.PostComments, function (item) { return new    Comment(item); });
    self.PostComments(mappedPosts);
  }
  self.toggleComment = function (item,event) {       
    $(event.target).next().find('.publishComment').toggle();
  }
}

// Comment Model:

function Comment(data) {
  var self = this;
  data = data || {};   
  self.CommentId = data.CommentId;
  self.PostId = data.PostId;
  self.Message = ko.observable(data.Message || "");
  self.CommentedBy = data.CommentedBy || "";
  self.CommentedByAvatar = data.CommentedByAvatar || "";
  self.CommentedByName = data.CommentedByName || "";
  self.CommentedDate = getTimeAgo(data.CommentedDate);
  self.error = ko.observable();    
}

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.posts = ko.observableArray();
  self.newMessage = ko.observable();
  self.error = ko.observable();
  self.loadPosts = function () {
    //To load existing posts
    $.ajax({
        url: postApiUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET'
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            var mappedPosts = $.map(data, function (item) { return new Post(item); });
            self.posts(mappedPosts);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            error('unable to load posts');
        });
  }

  self.addPost = function () {
    var post = new Post();
    post.Message(self.newMessage());
    return $.ajax({
        url: postApiUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data:  ko.toJSON(post)
    })
   .done(function (result) {           
       self.posts.splice(0,0,new Post(result));
       self.newMessage('');
     })
   .fail(function () {
            error('unable to add post');
    });
 }
 self.loadPosts();
 return self;
}; 

ko.applyBindings(new  viewModel(),documentgetElementByClassName(publishContainer));
```

Comment: and BTW you are missing a `.` after `document` in `documentgetElementByClassName`

Comment: If you want to access `addComment` from outside of `posts` it has to be out of `Post` class.

Comment: so its impossible to have click event in class, bcoz i am using same class name in ko.applybindings

Answer (score 0):

One option to your problem is that there should be an `observable`
which holds the selectedPost / currentPost. This prop should be updated before you press on Add Comment

Then update your viewModel like the below one.

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.posts = ko.observableArray();
    self.newMessage = ko.observable();
    self.error = ko.observable();
    self.loadPosts = function() {
        //To load existing posts
        $.ajax({
                url: postApiUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                type: 'GET'
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                var mappedPosts = $.map(data, function(item) {
                    return new Post(item);
                });
                self.posts(mappedPosts);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                error('unable to load posts');
            });
    }

    self.addPost = function() {
        var post = new Post();
        post.Message(self.newMessage());
        return $.ajax({
                url: postApiUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: ko.toJSON(post)
            })
            .done(function(result) {
                self.posts.splice(0, 0, new Post(result));
                self.newMessage('');
            })
            .fail(function() {
                error('unable to add post');
            });
    }

    self.selectedPost = ko.observable(); // You have to update this property, before you click on Add Comment from second view.

    self.addComment = function() {
        var comment = new Comment();
        comment.PostId = self.selectedPost.PostId;
        comment.Message(self.newCommentMessage());
        return $.ajax({
                url: commentApiUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                data: ko.toJSON(comment)
            })
            .done(function(result) {
                self.selectedPost.PostComments.push(new Comment(result));
                self.newCommentMessage('');
            })
            .fail(function() {
                error('unable to add post');
            });
    }

    self.loadPosts();
    return self;
};
```

And, in your so called first view, update the Add Comment part as shown below

```
<div style="display: block" class="publishComment">
                <textarea class="commentTextArea" data-bind="value: newCommentMessage, jqAutoresize: {}" placeholder="write a comment..."></textarea>
                <input type="button"  value="Comment" class="btnComment" data-bind="click: $parent.addComment"/>
            </div>
```

Comment: @thanks,i am getting postID and sending value to api,but on suceess i have use PostComments variable inside which hold the all object arrary, in loadpost its my "get method " which i bring all the data post and comments both and mapping view using foreach"PostComments",now if use different method to post,how i can use "PostComment" in same foreach loop

Comment: I am not getting you. What is your problem now?

Comment: first i ll call self.loadPosts method,i ll get all post and comment details on success of sel.loadPost, i am passing data to post model there i am checking whether the data is comment or post,i am checking the condition,if (data.PostComments) {return new    Comment(item)})}, passing to comment Model, now on click of addComment i need to add comment to particular post but i am already using PostComments variable in Foreachloop for comment binding,now if add addComment click event in viewModel,i cant access PostComments variable which used before in foreach loop i need to create new variable

Comment: so i need to use click event inside the post class,so i can bind it,but problem is add comment is in different page,i am not able to get click event inside post model,i need solution for that